# Sony eBook Library for Mac No Longer Displays Its Window

Tags: mac, ebook

I got a Sony PRS-505 reader a few weeks ago, and the Sony eBook Library 3.0 software worked fine on my Mac, until today.  Now, when I launch it, the menu bar is displayed, but there is no application window and the menu items have no effect.

I've reinstalled the software, but that didn't help.  I've deleted `~/Library/Preferences/Sony Corporation`, but that didn't help.

I suppose I could start using Calibre exclusively, except it would make it difficult to buy books from Sony's ebookstore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer here: http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=59980

Delete these directories:

- /Applications/eBookLibrary
- /Library/eBookLibrary
- /Users/(yourname)/Library/Preferences/Sony Corporation
- /Users/(yourname)/Library/Preferences/fsk
- /Users/(yourname)/Library/Preferences/Marlin

Then reinstall the software.

Note that deleting those directories will delete all your books, so make backups of anything you want to keep.  Anything you've purchased from the Sony e-bookstore can be re-downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

This the best solution to reset a messed up GUI of Sony Reader Library software:

Rename or delete the 'kinoma' folder.

This hidden 'kinoma' folder is located here (Windows 7)
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\kinoma
or C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\kinoma (Windows XP)

You will not need to re-install anything, and all e-books are still available.

Thanks,
Erwin

Answer (score 1):

By the way, on Mac OSX you can fix a messed up GUI for Sony Reader Library by deleting this file:

~/Library/Preferences/fsk/1/com.kinoma.fskin.ktStart-kBook.xml

Again, no need to re-install or to lose e-books.